# Implementing Publisher/Subscriber bus for two Azure table storage

Tags: azure, data-binding, azure-table-storage, database-trigger

I have two Azure storage tables:

Table 1:  This table is being updated regularly with a background task.
Table 2:  Contains a subset of entities of table 1, but it need to be updated whenever there is a change in table 1.

```
| Table 2 |      | Table 1 |
|         |      |    A    |
|    B    |      |    B    |
|    C    |  <=> |    C    |   
|    D    |      |    D    |
|         |      |    E    |
|         |      |    F    |
```

Basically what I want to achieve here is that Table 1 should always be listening to table 2 and whenever I add an entity to table 2, table 1 should know that I am interested in tracking that item and update both entities when there is an update available.

Comment: Looks like a prime candidate for Azure functions with triggers: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-triggers-bindings#overview

Comment: Is it a practical solution given that you have millions of entries?

Comment: No idea, mate. Never had to do this with millions of records. But lack of description of your architecture and available infrastructure does not help with a better answer.

Comment: The background task is an ASP. Net application that updates table 1. Table 1 is  a pool of product prices that changes dynamically and I only wanna listen to price changes related to my products listed in table 2.

Answer (score 0):

Well, here is a suggestion:

1. Have the background task send a message to a Service Bus Queue containing a reference to the changed entity
2. Make an Azure Function that listens to the queue, and it can check if an entity matching the updated one exists in the other table
3. If one does, it can update it

More info: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-service-bus

Support might be added in future for these events in Azure Event Grid.
When that happens, it can remove the need to post events about table changes, and you would only need the Event Grid subscription + Azure Function.

Comment: Thanks! Do you know the time complexity of this solution? I am dealing with millions of entities that are changing in real time.

Comment: I think that depends on how you will search for the matching row in the other table. If you have the partition and row key, it is O(1).

Comment: If for some reasons I am not allowed to modify the background task, am I out of lock here?

Comment: If Event Grid does not support Table Storage notifications, then in this particular case your only remaining option would be a scheduled sync. But that one scales a bit more poorly :/ If you used Cosmos DB, there would be a change feed you can listen to.

Comment: Can I even use Cosmos DB instead of Azure table?

Comment: Well in this case if you can't modify the background task, then you couldn't use it of course :) The APIs are a bit different, in Cosmos you would probably store the data as a JSON document.